# Book found inside baneswood

Tags: darksiders-2

As I entered baneswood following the left side of the mountains in the forge lands. I came across a book on top of a post. I can't seem to find any information about it also I can't pick it up. I can move it around, but I can't put it in my inventory with all the other items. Can you please help me figure out what this book is?

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the quest 'Makers Chronicle', which you can take after completing a side quest called 'Wandering Stone' (You have to find his 2 legs and 2 arms).

Note that 'Makers Chronicle' is available if you have the 'Death Rides' DLC.

> If you talk to Oran after finishing the Wandering Stone side quest he will assign you with another one.  He talks about a time about a lost item called the Maker's Chronicle. It has long been lost and he hopes to give it back to the Makers but he needs your help to do so.  He tells you to go speak to Muria back at the Tri-Stone.
>
> Once you get back to the Tri-Stone go talk to Muria.  There she will tell you that she doesnt know where it is but that she can give you an item that will help you locate it's where abouts. However, there is a catch.  Muria asks you to first collect for her 6 life seeds for her practices.
>
> These items are pretty common in enemies you kill.  If you can find a large assortment of enemies.  The easiest place to get these is the Fjord or Drenchfort.  There you can find a respawning insect like enemy and hive.  By continually killing the insects and leaving the hive alone you can gather the life seeds in no time flat.
>
> Once the seeds are gather head back to Muria and she will reward you with the Lodestone.  The Lodestone will allow you to locate the Chronicle, which if you bring up the map and set the quest to active will allow you to track it down no problem. Fast travel to Baneswood and you can locate the Chronicle there.
>
> After locating the Chronicle take it to Oran and you will finish the quest.

Source: http://www.ign.com/wikis/darksiders-2/Makers_Chronicle